# Intercept a click on submit button and check validity of form jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I want to check validity of form on clicking the submit button. In case it is valid the form should submit otherwise do nothing.
I've tried disabling the submit button and on click checking validity and enabling it.
But I see two issues with this approach.
1: Clicks are not detected on a disabled button
2: Even if I manage to get a click detected, I'll probably end up in an infinite loop. The second click after the button is enabled will again trigger the validity check and so in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `event.preventDefault()`. Read this: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Rough sample code draft:

```
$('your-submit-button').click(function(event){
    if (! validate() ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        showErrors();
    }
})
```

Where `validate()` is your validation function, returning false in case of validation fail.

**Edit:**
Sample handler is bind to `click` event, because you want

> to check validity of form on clicking the submit button

It's better practice to use `.submit()` instead of `.click()`, for validation to be made for any type of form submitting. 
Our sample stays almost unchanged:

```
$('#your-form-id').submit(function(event){
    if (! validate() ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        showErrors();
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked perfectly :>